# Separate string by comma and convert to associative array

Tags: php, string

I have a string `"key1=value1,key2=value2,...,key-n=value-n"`.

Without knowing what n is, how can I parse the string to an associative array like:

```
$result = ["key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2",...,"key-n" => "value-n"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example it seems like you just want to extract and separate keys and values.

```
$result = [];
foreach (explode(',', $string) as $pair) {
  list($key, $value) = explode('=', $pair);
  $result[$key] = $value;
}
```

If you need to throw some regex magic to make sure it conforms to a certain syntax. Here is an example:

```
$result = [];
foreach (explode(',', $string) as $pair) {
  if (!preg_match('#^(.+-?.*)=(.+-?.*)$#', $pair, $matches)) continue;
  $result[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
}
```

Comment: A working simple implementation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is a valid solution if, and only if, none of the fields have commas.   Consider `$csv =  "last, first","1234 N Main St., New York, NY"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the string as a CSV then explode on the `=` signs.

```
$array = str_getcsv('key1=value1,key2=value2,...,key-n=value-n');
$newarray = array();
foreach($array as $pairs){
    if(strpos($pairs, '=') !== FALSE){
        list($key, $value) = explode('=', $pairs);
        $newarray[$key] = $value;
    } else {
        //no value present, what to do?
    }
}
print_r($newarray);
```

https://3v4l.org/hkYil

Comment: Can u tell me the difference between explode and str_getcsv?

Comment: `str_getcsv` is for parsing a CSV, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php, can also be used for other strings with delimiters. You can define the delimiter, enclosure character, as well as an escape character for the data. Explode can't do those things.

Comment: Many thanks, however I just need a simpler solution, so I'll go with tim's answer.